# Chef Client installation and nodes configuration

Tags: chef-infra

As per my understanding chef works on pull mechanism . So whenever any update comes on chef server then the nodes configure themselves by pulling those updates from chef server. But to pull those updates chef client should be present on the respective nodes. Hence I need to understand if there are 100 nodes then do I need to install the chef client one by one on all 100 nodes. I believe no . So there must be some technique to install the chef client and configure on all 100 nodes in 1 go. Can you please advise.

Answer (score 0):

> nodes configure themselves

there is no such auto-configurations. you will have to configure the nodes to do so and you can do it several ways:

- configure the nodes to run chef-client periodically (as a deamon). [chef-client cookbook](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/chef-client) might be handy for setting it up
- configure the nodes to run chef-client on demand. this can can be done using knife, by [querying](https://docs.chef.io/knife_search.html#query-syntax) for relevant nodes and execute chef-client

> if there are 100 nodes then do I need to install the chef client one by one on all 100 nodes. I believe no

your believes are incorrect. that is, you will have to install chef-client on all of the nodes

> there must be some technique to install the chef client and configure on all 100 nodes in 1 go

you will have to [bootstrap each node](https://docs.chef.io/install_bootstrap.html#knife-bootstrap).